# Insert Into local database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce

I can't Insert and select from Local database data in C#.

I've read these articles

- [C# - Writing data in local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533170/c-sharp-writing-data-in-local-database)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection(v=vs.100).aspx
- [How to add local database items into textBox using listBox in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082793/how-to-add-local-database-items-into-textbox-using-listbox-in-c-sharp)

All the code samples are the same, here's my sample.

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PacjenciDB.sdf");
conn.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO pacjenci (nazwiskoimie,adres,skierowany,opis) values (@nazwiskoimie,@adres,@skierowany,@opis)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nazwiskoimie", txtnazwiskoimie.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adres", txtadres.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skierowany", txtskierowany.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opis", txtopis.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried tons of samples about insert data, but it doesn't work.

I can manage `.MDF`, but `.SDF` seems quite problematic.

Hope you help me

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing? Do you get an error?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, after execute code I clicked Show Table Data and select * from, and DB is empty (NULL,NULL...). I've tried in try/catch, but there aren't any errors

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't access a DB like that; why not use Linq-To-SQL or Linq-To-Entities?

Comment: I want to create an application with Local Database, LocalDB has .sdf extension

Comment: Localdb is not meant for application deployment, only development. FIrst page of the documentation pretty much sentence one tells you about that. On top, LOCALDB HAS NOT THE SDF EXTESION - that is SQL EMBEDDED (SqlCE) which is also the classe you use. Please get your basics straight.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but It is strange why I can't do anything with localdb (insert, select,delete..) any ideas?

Comment: Well, maybe you should start reading up the basic documentation. FOr example - LocalDB does not use the SQL CE connection classes. Why can a car not fly? It is not a plane, dude. SqlCeConnection and SqlCOnnection are somehow quite different.

Comment: I know, then I using SQL CE for localDB as it writen in documentation, and lots of samples in StackOverflow, look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533170/c-sharp-writing-data-in-local-database I don't know what to do...

Comment: Man, did you ever read documentation? LocalDB is not "local database". DIfferent words, different meanings. THe question you links to is not using LocalDb at all.

Comment: Sry, I'm newbie.I've solved my problem. I've created new project, created new DB Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5, and it works, is it correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm going to take a guess here. Is the PacjenciDB.sdf included into Visual Studio project by any chance? Do you have the property "Copy to output folder" set to "Always" or something similar? It seems that every time you do a build you could be overwriting your output folder database file. Try putting the database in a folder that is not inside VS project.

BTW, your code is OK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem was with the path of my .sdf file, I had .sdf in bin/debug and in files project second .sdf with the same name, in VS I set query DB in project folder, but String Connection was set to |DataDirectory| Thank you for Your help! Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Look for a copy of the database with data in your bin/debug folder.

Solution is to not use |DataDirectory|, but use full path instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem was with the path of my .sdf file, I had .sdf in bin/debug and in files project second .sdf with the same name, in VS I set query DB in project folder, but String Connection was set to |DataDirectory| Thank you for Your help! Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The above code is correct and most likely the problem is somewhere else, where you call that code from. If there is a problem with db connection or data is wrong - you should get an exception. Since there is no error occurred and no new records added - the code is not executed at all.

P.S.

.sdf is a Sql Server Compact Local Database, so using System.Data.SqlServerCe is correct
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem was with the path of my .sdf file, I had .sdf in bin/debug and in files project second .sdf with the same name, in VS I set query DB in project folder, but String Connection was set to |DataDirectory| Thank you for Your help! Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

Try using double backslash when setting the path to your database file:

```
string dbPath + "Data Source=C:\\DataDirectory\\PacjenciDB.sdf";
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(dbPath);
conn.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO pacjenci (nazwiskoimie,adres,skierowany,opis) values (@nazwiskoimie,@adres,@skierowany,@opis)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nazwiskoimie", txtnazwiskoimie.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adres", txtadres.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skierowany", txtskierowany.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opis", txtopis.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Comment: The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source = \PacjenciDB.sdf ]

Comment: OP has a `@` before Data source which is the same when you have double backslash