# C# Database not updating from dataset. SQLCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, sql-server

Problem that's been gripping me for last 4hours.My dataset gets the changes,but the database doesnt.

Stuff that just lies around as a "global" var :

```
    DatabaseConnection objConnect;        
    string conString;
    DataSet ds;
    int MaxRows;
```

My form load initializes db connections:

```
            objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
            conString = Properties.Settings.Default.memoDbConnectionString;
            objConnect.connection_string = conString;
```

I've got this button that changes my dataset and calls my db update.

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //

        objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.userSQL;
        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;
        MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxRows; i++)
        {
            DataRow dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            if (nick == dRow.ItemArray[0].ToString())
                if (textBox4.Text == textBox5.Text)
                    if (textBox3.Text == dRow.ItemArray[1].ToString())
                    {
                        ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] = textBox5.Text;
                       //this is the interesting bit
                        DataSet changes = ds.GetChanges();

                            objConnect.UpdateDatabase(changes);

                        //-----
                        MessageBox.Show(nick);
                        MessageBox.Show(dRow[1].ToString());

                        break;
                    }
                    else MessageBox.Show("Old password is wrong.");
                else MessageBox.Show("Pass confirmation does not correspond.");
                    }
        }
```

the function that i use in the DatabaseConnection class:

```
    public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        System.Data.DataSet changes = ds.GetChanges();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
        //stuff thats suppsed to help
        da_1.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
        //----
            da_1.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
        ds.AcceptChanges();
    }
```

da_1 is an sqlDataAdapter that i declare outside the function,but attribute it inside a function just before this one.

Comment: I have just found that it reads from one database and writes to another for some reason.my connection string is: Visual Studio 2015\Projects\memo\memo\Resources\memoDb.mdf

Comment: In solution explorer it says my db is ignored,the one thats actually in the path.

Answer (score 0):

This answer:

```
Ok, I'm going to take a guess here. Is the PacjenciDB.sdf included 
into Visual Studio project by any chance? Do you have the property" Copy 
to output folder" set to "Always" or something similar? It seems 
that every time you do a build you could be overwriting 
your output folder database file. Try putting the database in a folder 
that is not inside VS project.

 BTW, your code is OK.
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104947/insert-into-local-database-c-sharp) post helped me.
One thing to note is,if u start the program from the debug folder it will have no problems and that helped me find the issue.The problem was in the fact that I added my db into the project as a data source as well as making that connection string and its similarity with eachother.Deleting it from Data sources and adding it anew from the correct folder in the solution explorer fixed it for me.